# Jprofiler and websphere 8

Tags: websphere-8, jprofiler

Will you help me configure JProfiler with websphere 8 remoting mode.

What are the steps to follow to make this configuration.

Websphere is running on AIX 64-bit

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can profile any JVM with JProfiler by adding a special VM parameter to the invocation of the JVM.

Invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

in JProfiler's main menu and follow the steps in the wizard to get the VM parameter for your platform and JVM.

Comment: My question is how to configure the remote machine: I added a JVM parameter via the administration console whebsphere (Application servers> server1> Process definition> Java Virtual Machine 
), But the profile don't start.

The parameter is: 
-agentpath: /home/mobigim/jprofiler8/bin/aix-ppc64/libjprofilerti.so=port=11002

Comment: It does not start because it's waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI. See the native stderr output of the Websphere server. To avoid that, append `,nowait` to the -agentpath parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) EN JPROFILER

An application a remote computer -> On a Remote Computer ->  Linux x86 /amd64 ->

jvm vendor -> oracle
version -> 1.7.0
mode -> hotspot

64 bit jvm check.

wait for a connection from the profiler gui.

specify the remote address ->

remote installation directory -> /opt/xxxx/jprofiler

default port: 8849.

start.

2) Previously you should copy the zip that the wizard gave u on that folder.

 /opt/xxxx/jprofiler

3) At web sphere:

https://xx.xx.xx.xx:9043/ibm/console

Server -> Server type -> Webspher application servers -> Server1 -> Java and Process Management -> Process Definition -> Java Virtual Machine - > Generic Java Arguments

Add this line:

-Xshareclasses:none -agentpath:/opt/xxxx/jprofiler/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849
```